# Facebook graphi api explorer comments filtered by author

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

i've been playing around with the graph API explorer here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer , but I can't seem to find a way to get the comments from a specific person. My goal is to obtain all comment from a certain person in a group. I'm able to get all the comments in that group using the following:

```
1234567890/feed?fields=comments.fields(from,message)&limit=10
```

but that give the last 10 comments from anyone in there. I need to specify the name/ID of one person.

Any help there will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using the following FQL query:

```
SELECT text FROM comment WHERE post_id IN 
(SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = {Group_ID} LIMIT 500) 
AND fromid = {User_ID}
```

Replace the **{Group_ID}** with the Group Id that you are searching in and **{User_ID}** with the User Id of the user whose comments you want to retrieve.